# I get an error while running this program

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Arrayss3 {

    public static void printArray(double a[]) {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random gen=new Random();
        double [] a=new double[10];
        Arrayss3 ar=new Arrayss3();

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            a[i]=gen.nextInt(141)+60;
            System.out.println(printArray(a[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the error it is giving me when I run it:

```
Arrayss3.java:20: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to double[]
System.out.println(printArray(a[i]));
                               ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Comment: Please format your code like you're proud of it.

Comment: `printArray(a)` would make more sense, since `a` is a `double[]` and `printArray` expects a `double[]`

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**

You added "double a[]" as an argument of printArray while you've used it as only "double".

**Recommendations:**

- I recommend you to use Random gen = new Random(); outside of your main method in case you want to use it again in any other method, for better performance like lowering the memory used. Make sure to make it static.
- You used Arrayss3 ar = new Arrayss3(); while you are already in Arrayss3 class. Just use printArray without the need of this object.
- You're printing out a method that is not returning anything. Use something like this if you want this method to return:

  ```
  static Random gen = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      double[] a = new double[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          a[i] = gen.nextInt(141) + 60;
      }
      for (Double value : printArray(a)) {
          System.out.println(value);
      }
  }

  public static ArrayList<Double> printArray(double a[]) {
      ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          arrayList.add(a[i]);
      }
      return arrayList;
  }
  ```

  }

**Final code:**

You need to use something like this in order to let it work.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Arrayss3 {
    static Random gen = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = gen.nextInt(141) + 60;
        }
        printArray(a);
    }

    public static void printArray(double a[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Towards the end of your program:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  a[i]=gen.nextInt(141)+60;
  System.out.println(printArray(a[i]));  // error
}
```

You call `printArray()` with `a[i]` but `printArray` is declared to take a `double[]`, not an individual element.  Probably you want to move that statement after the loop, and remove the `println`.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  a[i]=gen.nextInt(141)+60;
}
printArray(a);
```